# Survival with unknown birth time and large observation time resolution

Tags: modeling, survival

Suppose at $t=0$, we have a box with nothing in it, then 8 hours after at $t=8$, we look in the box and find inside $N$ cells that have appeared. 
Over these $N$ cells, $D$ are dead and $L=N-D$ are alive. We suppose that the cells are appearing independently and randomly between $t=0$ and $t=8$ and dying independently according to an unknown law.

Then we would like to infer from these data, statistics of the life duration of the cell. How can we solve this problem ?

Comment: There are several names: "coarse data" (Heitjan, Daniel F. "Ignorability and coarse data: Some biomedical examples." Biometrics (1993): 1099-1109.) or partially identified models (Gustafson, Paul. Bayesian Inference for Partially Identified Models: Exploring the Limits of Limited Data. Vol. 140. Crc Press, 2015.). The only idea for solving your particular problem that I had was Approximate Bayesian Computation, if you have candidate models from which you can simulate (with so little and discrete data you could even require an exact match between simulated and actual data).

Comment: Are you only looking once? Or are you observing at $t = 8, 16, 24,...$? If you are observing multiple times, it is reasonable to treat this as bivariate interval censored data.

Comment: @Cliff AB. Yes I am observing at t=8,16,24 ... and I can label the living cells at observation time so that I can identified from which "generation" comes the dead cells at the next observation. Thanks for you suggestion, I will look at it.